# Check if a string is solely composed of characters found in another string

Tags: php, validation, character, matching, whitelist

Considering sample data such as:

```
$str1 = "apple";
$str2 = "pal";
```

I want to return a `true` response only if all the characters [alphabetical characters] of the `$str2` are also present in `$str1`, otherwise `false`.

Since all letters `p`, `a`, and `l` all exist in `$str1`, then result should be `true`.

If `$str2` was `pole`, then the `p`, `l`, and `e` would be found, but the `o` would not.  This scenario should return `false`.

My pseudo code is:

```
if (str2 is present in str1){
    // true;
    // since all characters of str2 are also in str1, so it should return true.
} else{
    // false;
}
```

Comment: are you talking about individual characters or grouped-characters?

Comment: Individual characters, with random position.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Fellow volunteers, this question is not Unclear.  There is a pseudo-coding attempt, so it is certainly not the worst case of help vampirism that we commonly see here.  Could it have been researched harder and had a better coding attempt? Sure, but that is not a close reason.  I do not agree with the dupe nomination -- and I feel it should be retracted.  If this page is closed without a better dupe nomination, I will be voting to reopen.

Comment: @mickmackusa sure, sir. :)

Comment: If you only deleted the comment, that is not the same as "Retracting your close vote".  Please click the Close hyperlink (again), and then Retract from the popup modal. @Omi  (there were 2 close votes, and there are still 2 close votes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the first string (whitelist string) as the mask for `trim()`.  This will remove all matched characters from the second string.  If there are any characters remaining after the trim, then `false`.

> since all characters of str2 are also in str1, so it should return true

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/IVlI3))

```
$str1 = "apple";
$str2 = "pal";
$str3 = "pole";
var_export(!strlen(trim($str2, $str1)));
echo "\n---\n";
var_export(!strlen(trim($str3, $str1)));
```

Output:

```
true
---
false
```

This answer is clean and direct because it does not need to generate temporary arrays for subsequent comparison.  `trim()`'s character mask affords the same action that `str_replace()` is famous for, but without needing to split the whitelist string into an array first.  I don't know if `ltrim()` or `rtrim()` would be any faster (on a microscopic level) than `trim()`, but any of these functions will deliver the same output.

---

p.s. If you are **guaranteed** to only be working with letters, then you can use a falsey check instead of `strlen()`.

```
!trim($str2, $str1)
```

I say this because if you allowed numbers, then a trimmed string containing a zero would be considered falsey and return an incorrect result.

Comment: Just like a master, sir. Clean and short.  You're an inspiration. <3

Comment: Wow ❤️ Thanks a lot. This is what i was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [array_intersect](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php) function after splitting each characters from a word using the [str_split](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php) function as:

```
<?php

$a = "Apple";
$b = "pal";

$matched = !empty(array_intersect(str_split($b), str_split($a)));
```

> array_intersect will return [ p, l ] ignoring 'A' due to case
> sensitive

```
echo $matched; // true

?>
```

In case if you want to match ignoring the case of the characters then you can first lowercase the word using the [strtolower](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php) function: and then split as:

```
$a = "Apple";

$a = strtolower($a);
```

Comment: It is not what i am looking for. It gives true response even when one character matches and the rest doesn’t match. 

What i want is, it should give true response only when all the characters of str2 are present in str1.

Comment: `!empty()` is more simply replaced by `(bool)`.

Comment: @Umar then you should have told earlier. Let me edit.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [count_chars()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.count-chars.php) to get array of present chars in each string and then compare those two arrays:

```
$s1 = 'apple';
$s2 = 'pal';

$c1 = count_chars($s1, 1);
$c2 = count_chars($s2, 1);

$ok = empty(array_diff_key($c2, $c1));
```

Comment: `empty()` is appropriate when the variable/data passed in might be undeclared.  In this case, you are sure to have _some kind of data_.  `empty()` can be replaced by `!`.